# Correlating JButton with Functionality, Changing the color of a line

Tags: java, jbutton

I am new to JButton and JFrame and just trying to learn some basics, about how logic should work and what the code should look like. Here, I have created an idea of logic, but it doesn't work. I am not sure if I just need to tweak something or if I'm going about this completely wrong. Again, I'm new to this, just trying to learn the basics. Thank you for any help. What it should do is change the color of the line when the button is clicked. :)

```
JButton yellow = new JButton();

    public SimplePaint(){

    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    yellow.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    panel.add(yellow);  

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(0, 250, 2000, 300);
    g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g2.draw(line);

    JButton color = null;

    if (color == yellow) {
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
```

Update: I have implemented the below answer, and I think I am getting closer, but the functionality is still not working. Here is the updated code:

```
JButton action =new JButton();
JButton red = new JButton();
JButton blue = new JButton(); 

public SimplePaint() {

blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);    
    panel.add(blue);

red.setBackground(Color.RED);
    panel.add(red);

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Line2D line = new Line2D.Float(0, 250, 2000, 300);
    g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    g2.draw(line);    

    action.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == blue) {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == red) {
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
        repaint();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Where is the code to change to color of the line when the button is clicked ?

Comment: I thought it would be JButton color = null; and then if (color == yellow), change the line color to yellow. Is this logic not correct?

Comment: No because color is never initialized (hence is equal to null) and if it were initialized and not directly set to yellow they could not possibly equal each other since they are seperate instances of a JButton

Comment: Okay, so how would I fix this logic? What would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a listener to the buttons, so they can trigger actions

```
jBUtton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    System.out.println("Button Pressed");
    //pressed = !pressed; // if you want to toggle
    pressed = true;
    this.repaint(); // you need to refresh the screen 
  } 
} );
```

after that

```
if(pressed)
    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
else
    g2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is too incomplete for us to really see what is wrong. 
You define a SimplePaint constructor (but do not show how SimplePaint is declared - does it extend some class like JPanel of JFrame ? ). then you illegally define a paint() mathod inside that constructor.

First of all, it is rarely a good idea to extend JFrame. Your class should extend JPanel instead, and you should override paintComponent(), not paint(). Then you just create a JFrame and add your SimplePaint instance to it.